# How is the push forward map constructed on smooth projective varieties?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry

I am learning about De Rham cohomology cohomology on smooth complex projective varieties. If $\phi : X \rightarrow Y$ is morphism between two smooth projective varieties. I have seen that the push forward is defined and there exists the following map$P : H^{p,q}(X) \rightarrow H^{p - r,q - r}(Y)$, where $r = dim(X) - dim(Y)$. I haven't seen how it is exactly defined? For the sake of simplicity let us say $dim(X) = dim(Y)$. Can someone tell me how it is defined  (I am new to math stackexchange, so please be patient with me if I made any mistakes in how I phrased my question).

Comment: Shouldn’t the $2r$ be just $r$? Then this is the Gysin map or integration over the fiber.

Comment: @TedShifrin Yeah. It should be r. That was a typo. Can you tell you tell me where I could find information about the exact definition using Gysin map or integration over the fiber? I prefer integration, that seems more algebraic and intuitive.

Comment: You can find information by searching here and on wikipedia. But, very simply, it’s the result of interpreting the usual pushforward on homology via Poincaré duality (so cap with the fundamental class of the general fiber).

Comment: Ok. That makes sense. Ty!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\dim_{\mathbb C}X = n$ and $\dim_{\mathbb C} Y = m$.
The map $\phi: X \to Y$ induces a pull-back morphism
$$\phi^*: H^k(Y, \mathbb C) \to H^k(X, \mathbb C), [\alpha] \mapsto [\phi^* \alpha].$$
On the other hand, the the pairing
\begin{align*}
H^k(X, \mathbb C) \otimes H^{n-k}(X, \mathbb C) \to \mathbb C \\
[\alpha] \otimes [\beta] \mapsto \int_X \alpha \wedge \beta
\end{align*}
is a perfect pairing (this is called the Poincaré duality theorem, see [1, Thm 5.30]), so that naturally $H^k(X, \mathbb C) \cong H^{n-k}(X, \mathbb C)^*$. Hence the dual map of $\phi^*$ gives a morphism
$$\phi_*: H^{2n-k}(X, \mathbb C) \to H^{2m-k}(Y, \mathbb C).$$
Set $2n - k = p+q$ to obtain
$$\phi_*: H^{p+q}(X, \mathbb C) \to H^{p+q - 2r}(Y, \mathbb C).$$
It remains to verify that this maps $H^{p,q}$ to $H^{p-r, q-r}$, which follows from the fact that pull-back preserves Hodge-type, i.e. $$\phi^*: H^{p,q}(Y) \to H^{p,q}(X).$$

[1] Voisin, *Hodge Theory and Complex Algebraic Geometry*